# Elegant way to get range of values from two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below (run the full code below)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,21,31,41,51],
                        'date_birth': ['05/29/1967', '01/21/1957', '7/27/1959','01/01/1961','12/31/1961']})
df1 = df1.melt('person_id', value_name='date_birth')
df1['birth_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_birth'])
df_ranges = df1.assign(until_prev_year_days=(df1['birth_dates'].dt.dayofyear - 1),
     until_next_year_days=((df1['birth_dates'] + pd.offsets.YearEnd(0)) - df1['birth_dates']).dt.days)
f = {'until_prev_year_days': 'min', 'until_next_year_days': 'min'}

min_days = df_ranges.groupby('person_id',as_index=False).agg(f)
min_days.columns = ['person_id','no_days_to_prev_year','no_days_to_next_year']
df_offset = pd.merge(df_ranges[['person_id','birth_dates']], min_days, on='person_id',how='inner')
```

See below on what I tried to get the range

```
df_offset['range_to_shift'] = "[" + (-1 * df_offset['no_days_to_prev_year']).map(str) + "," + df_offset['no_days_to_next_year'].map(str) + "]"
```

**Though my approach works, I would like to is there any better and elegant way to do the same**

Please note that for values from `no_days_to_prev_year`, we have to prefix `minus` sign

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Do you want  range as `list` or `string` type in `range_to_shift` column?

Comment: can help with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62552439/elegant-way-to-shift-dates-from-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) along with [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
cols = ['no_days_to_prev_year', 'no_days_to_next_year']
df_offset['range_to_shift'] = df_offset[cols].mul([-1, 1]).to_numpy().tolist()
```

Result:

```
# print(df_offset)

   person_id birth_dates  no_days_to_prev_year  no_days_to_next_year range_to_shift
0         11  1967-05-29                   148                   216    [-148, 216]
1         21  1957-01-21                    20                   344     [-20, 344]
2         31  1959-07-27                   207                   157    [-207, 157]
3         41  1961-01-01                     0                   364       [0, 364]
4         51  1961-12-31                   364                     0      [-364, 0]
```

`timeit` performance results:

```
df_offset.shape
(50000, 5)

%%timeit -n100
cols = ['no_days_to_prev_year', 'no_days_to_next_year']
df_offset['range_to_shift'] = df_offset[cols].mul([-1, 1]).to_numpy().tolist()

15.5 ms ± 464 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `zip` to create your list of range:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,21,31,41,51],
                   'date_birth': ['05/29/1967', '01/21/1957', '7/27/1959','01/01/1961','12/31/1961']})
df['date_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_birth'],format="%m/%d/%Y")
df["day_to_prev"] = df['date_birth'].dt.dayofyear - 1
df["day_to_next"] = (pd.offsets.YearEnd(0) + df['date_birth'] - df["date_birth"]).dt.days
df["range_to_shift"] = [[-x, y] for x,y in zip(df["day_to_prev"],df["day_to_next"])]

print (df)

   person_id date_birth  day_to_prev  day_to_next range_to_shift
0         11 1967-05-29          148          216    [-148, 216]
1         21 1957-01-21           20          344     [-20, 344]
2         31 1959-07-27          207          157    [-207, 157]
3         41 1961-01-01            0          364       [0, 364]
4         51 1961-12-31          364            0      [-364, 0]
```